Agda case splitting with equality
I want to split x : Maybe into two case, just and nothing. When just case got called, I want to get definitional equality just a ≡ x and when nothing case got called, I want to get definitional equality nothing ≡ x. How can I do this?

That is already what happens: in the nothing branch, x is replaced with nothing in both the context and goal. If you need the replacement to occur somewhere else that Agda can't guess, you'll need to use generalisation (with abstraction). Sharing your code and what you're trying to achieve would probably get you more accurate answers.
